# Angular Static Injector Provider error - but only when extending another injectable

Tags: angular

I have an API based service that looks like this

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiBaseService {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        _configuration: ConfigurationService
    ) {
        this.apiUrl = _configuration.serverWithApiUrl;
    }
}
```

I am trying to extend this with something that looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class StaticTranslationService extends ApiBaseService {

  private staticTranslations = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor(
     http: HttpClient,
      _configuration: ConfigurationService
  ) {
    super(http, _configuration);
    this.staticTranslations.next(json);
  }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StaticTranslationService -> ConfigurationService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StaticTranslationService -> ConfigurationService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ConfigurationService!
```

however, my app.module providers look like this:

```
providers: [
    ConfigurationService,
    ApiBaseService,
    StaticTranslationService
  ]
```

ConfigurationService is injectable into other services that also extend ApiBaseService and working there - but they don't have their own constructor which is the only difference.

Anyone know the issue here, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do here is create ApiBaseService an abstract class and then extend it in other Injectable Services. Base services should never be marked as Injectable.

Comment: doing that I got Can't resolve all parameters for Service: (?, ?) for all services that extend.

so i put the constructor in all the services that extend and that got rid of this error, but i am still back to the original one

Comment: 1. Import HttpClientModule in the module which has StaticTranslationService in its providers. 2. Inject HttpClient in constructor of StaticTranslationService and pass it on to abstract class ApiBaseService. 3. Use abstract class methods by super.get/post etc.

Comment: base still needs config service - all steps listed i have already but double checked anyway. didnt work for me

Comment: I can see that you are using config service for api url, which should rather be taken from environment. Either create an env variable or a file that contains project wide constants and then use them.

Comment: config service takes it from environment Manu

I solved the issue - vccode has some kind of bug with auto imports when you import json into the same file it appends .js to all auto imports...so the config service was not quite right import.

anyway ill accept your answer since it made me implement the abstract class. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Craig Always a pleasure. :)